# What would be better way of polling MongoDb MongoDB's collection.watch() or using sched.scheduler...?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, scheduler

I basically want to use Mongodb as queue to process requests. So I need to look for any new document added or even update made to existing document and process accordingly.

Currently I am using, which basically queries mongodb and then process data on fix intervals

```
sc = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

while True:
    sc.enter(3, 1, process_req,(db,))
    sc.run()
```

Comment: Could be more explicit on what doesn't work here?

Comment: I was wondering if mongo.watch() would be a better way to do it, instead of triggering a query every couple of seconds or so..?